# How do I unpivot/pivot dynamically while keeping original order of my columns?

Tags: sql-server, pivot, unpivot

I'm making an accounting report by performing a bunch of calculations on a table and transposing it by unpivoting/pivoting so it matches the format I want.

The problem is when I unpivot the columns into the rows the resulting output automatically sorts the rows by alphabetical order.  I want to know if there's a way to stop the unpivot from doing that and transposing the exact order of the columns into the rows.

Here's my code for the dynamic pivot/unpivot:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GenerateFormattedFFOReport

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @COLSUNPIVOT AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@QUERY  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@COLSPIVOT AS  NVARCHAR(MAX),
@COLSUNPIVOTORDER AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @COLSUNPIVOT = STUFF((SELECT ','+QUOTENAME(C.NAME)
FROM SYS.COLUMNS C  WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE C.OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('GenerateFFOReportData') AND C.NAME <> 'Quarter'
FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')

SELECT @COLSUNPIVOTORDER = STUFF

SELECT @COLSPIVOT = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME([Quarter])
FROM GenerateFFOReportData T FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')
SELECT @COLSUNPIVOT

SET @QUERY 
= 'SELECT HEADER, '+@COLSPIVOT+'
FROM
(
SELECT HEADER,[Quarter],VALUE FROM GenerateFFOReportData

UNPIVOT
(
VALUE FOR HEADER IN ('+@COLSUNPIVOT+')
) UNPIV
) SRC

PIVOT
(
SUM(VALUE)
FOR [Quarter] IN ('+@COLSPIVOT+')
) PIV'


EXEC (@QUERY)

END
GO
```

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Seeing your table structures, sample data and final desired result would make this much easier.  Also what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: This is easiest by using CROSS APPLY with a VALUES clause to perform the un-pivot, instead of explicitly using the (somewhat simplistic) built-in UNPIVOT clause. see http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/CROSS+APPLY+VALUES+UNPIVOT/91234/ or http://sqlstudies.com/2013/04/01/unpivot-a-table-using-cross-apply/ Then you can simply add an ordering field to each unpivoted row.